# Copy and paste few text to a new column in excel

Tags: vba, excel, filter

Hello Excel and Macro experts, I have an excel sheet where a particular column has the following text

- abcdef x: 12 Y: 56
- qwertyuiop x: 34 Y: 78
- asdfghlkjhfda x: 11 Y: 12

The task is to identify the numbers which appear after X: and paste them to a particular column. Also the number which is followed after Y: should be pasted to another column. There can be a row where the value of X and Y do not appear, in that case nothing needs to be pasted to the columns. I searched the web but could not find anything that fits my requirement.

I tried the following Macro which I found in the web.

```
Sub Macro1()
  Dim MatchString As String
  MatchString = "X: *"
  For Counter = 1 To Range("B:B").Count
    If (Left(Range("B" & Counter).Value, Len(MatchString)) = MatchString) Then
      Range("B" & Counter).Select
      Selection.Cut
      Range("D" & Counter).Select
      ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
  Next Counter
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Show different target columns for result than were in the original post
**EDIT2:** Show that there are column headers to be considered

To further Clarify following is the Excel Data
Column1 
Hearder 1
abcdef x: 12 Y: 56
qwertyuiop x: 34 Y: 78
asdfghlkjhfda x: 11 Y: 12

Column3 and Column4 do not have any data

After running the Macro it should be displayed as below
Column1 
 
Header1 
 
abcdef
qwertyuiop
asdfghlkjhfda

Column3 
Hearder3  
12
34
11

Column4  
Header4 
56
78
12

Any Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post specific issue on a specific code or formula you've tried or written. Also clarify how your data look like.

Comment: Please edit your question. Don't put clarification into comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this with formulas (except for the replacing of the contents of Column A, which you could do with a copy/paste-special values after the formulas

First Part:

```
=TRIM(LEFT($A1,MIN(SEARCH({"x:","y:"},$A1&"x:y:"))-1))
```

Number after x:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1E+307,--MID($A1,SEARCH("x:",$A1)+3,ROW(INDIRECT("1:99")))),"")
```

Number after y:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1E+307,--MID($A1,SEARCH("y:",$A1)+3,ROW(INDIRECT("1:99")))),"")
```

If you really want a macro, the following should do the trick.  It assumes your data is in column A starting with A1.  That starting point can be easily changed if necessary.  And it will overwrite column A.  X and Y can be in any order, or absent.  But it does assumes that the numbers are all integers.  If they might be decimals, that can be easily accounted for if we know whether there is, or is not, a mandatory integer portion.

**EDIT:**  The code has been changed to account for the OP's edited requirements that the results of the process be in columns A, C and D with column B being preserved:

**EDIT2:** Code altered to maintain headers and formatting

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Sub SplitAtXY()
    Dim R As Range
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Dim S As String
    Dim I As Long
    'Next line not needed since we are maintaining pre-existing format
    'Const lMinColWidth As Long = 10 '<--change as needed for appearance of results

V = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=2)

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .ignorecase = True
    .Pattern = "^(.*?)\s*([xy]):\s*(\d+)\s*(?!\2)([xy]):\s*(\d+)"
    .MultiLine = True
End With

ReDim Preserve V(1 To UBound(V), 1 To 4)
For I = 2 To UBound(V) '<--changed to 2 to maintain header rows as in original
        S = V(I, 1)
        If RE.test(S) Then
            Set MC = RE.Execute(S)
            V(I, 1) = MC(0).submatches(0)
            Select Case MC(0).submatches(1)
                Case "x"
                    V(I, 3) = MC(0).submatches(2)
                    V(I, 4) = MC(0).submatches(4)
                Case "y"
                    V(I, 3) = MC(0).submatches(4)
                    V(I, 4) = MC(0).submatches(2)
            End Select
        Else
            V(I, 1) = S
        End If
Next I

Set R = Range("a1").Resize(rowsize:=UBound(V, 1), columnsize:=UBound(V, 2))
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With R
    .EntireColumn.ClearContents '<--Changed to ClearContents to maintain previous formats
    .Value = V
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    For I = 1 To 4
        .Columns(I).ColumnWidth = WorksheetFunction.Max(.Columns(I).ColumnWidth, lMinColWidth)
    Next I
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome Macro, thanks a lot. Works perfectly. Appreciate the effort.

Comment: What part of the code should I modify to keep the column A intact ?

Comment: @user3156102 Does that mean that you don't want to break out what you called Column 1 separately?  Or that you want your Column 1 to be mapped to Column B, 2-->C  3-->D ?  If the latter, you would just set r to r.offset(0,1) before the last few lines that write the results.  If the former, you could just change the regex to always write the contents of col A to V(i,1).

Comment: Awesome, that was a quick reply. Thanks a Lot Ron !!1

Comment: I modified the above code to copy X,Y data from Column A to Column C and D. However if there is data in Column B, the data gets deleted. Can the code be modified to leave the data intact in Column B ?

Comment: @user3156102 Be very specific, as you were in your original post, as to how you want your output to look, with regard to columns A:D

Comment: Column 1 and 2 contains data. X and Y data from Column 1 should be copied to Column 3 and 4 respectively.

Comment: @user3156102 Is the contents of column A the same as what you show in your example?  Should the contents of column A be left unchanged, or should the x and y be removed from it as in the original code?

Comment: @user3156102 Never mind my last question.  I see your edit to your post

Comment: The revised code works but it deletes the Column header. Anyway that can be avoided ?

Comment: @user3156102 In your examples, you did not show what seemed to be any column headers.  Please elaborate -- and it'll be a day or two until I can get back to you.  But it'll be a simple fix with the proper information.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but I would like the Header and formatting of the columns to be unchanged when the data is moved. Please take your time. :)

Comment: @user3156102 If the headers are already there, then just change the processing to start at row 2 (i.e. for I = 2 to ubound(v).  To maintain the formatting, change the .Clear to .ClearContents

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a working solution BUT it relies on the formatting to be exactly as you described. If for example the user has more than 1 space between the X: and the number it won't work. (you can build in some more complexity to check for this though).

Assumptions:

- X will always be the first value defined
- the numbers are always 2 digits
- no extra spaces are included between X and number (or Y and number)

  ```
  Sub changeText()

  Dim lastRow As Integer
  Dim completeString As String
  Dim xPos As Integer
  Dim yPos As Integer

  'stop screen updating (speeds things up)
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  'set it so it is using the active sheet
  With ActiveSheet
      'find the last row of data
      lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

      'iterate through the rows until end (change i = 1 line to account for headings etc)    
      For i = 1 To lastRow
          'get the string from the cell
          completeString = Cells(i, 1).Value

          'find where the X: and Y: start                
          xPos = InStr(completeString, "X:")
          yPos = InStr(completeString, "Y:")
          'set the cells values to the first string, the X value and the Y value
          Cells(i, 1).Value = Left(completeString, xPos - 1)
          Cells(i, 2).Value = Mid(completeString, xPos + 3, 2)
          Cells(i, 3).Value = Mid(completeString, yPos + 3, 2)



      Next i

  End With
  'update screen again
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  End Sub
  ```

Oh and P.S. Your updated problem description was a thousand times better than the original and made the question answerable. (Although in future you will get more assistance from people if you show an active attempt at either writing your own code or modifying one to suit, rather than just trying something you found)